# How create a serializable C# class from XML file

Tags: c#, .net, object, xml-serialization

I am fairly new to XML in .net.  As part of my  task  i need to create the class which can be serialized to XML.  I have an sample XML file with all the tags(the class should produce XML  similar to the sample XML file ).  what  would be best approach to create the class  from XML file?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: have you had any luck with any of the suggested approaches?

Comment: Yes!. I successfully used the  xsd  tool  to generate the  class( i had to make couple of changes  to them  to meet my requirements).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use XSD.exe to create a .cs file from .xml.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx

At the command line:

```
xsd myFile.xml
xsd myFile.xsd
```

The first line will generate a schema definition file (xsd), the second file should generate a .cs file.  I'm not sure if the syntax is exact, but it should get you started.

Comment: 47 seconds too fast for me. +1. Can I add that `/c` would be the right output format?

Answer (score 4):

Working backwards might help -- create your class first, then serialize and see what you get.

For the simplest classes it's actually quite easy. You can use XmlSerializer to serialize, like:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\class.xml");

            MyClass firstInstance = new MyClass();
            firstInstance.SomeProperty = "foo"; // etc

            serializer.Serialize(writer, firstInstance);
            writer.Close();

            FileStream reader = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\class.xml", FileMode.Open);

            MyClass secondInstance = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This will write a serialized representation of your class in XML to "c:\temp\class.xml". You could take a look and see what you get. In reverse, you can use serializer.Deserialize to instantiate the class from "c:\temp\class.xml".

You can modify the behaviour of he serialization, and deal with unexpected nodes, etc -- take a look at [the XmlSerializer MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) for example.

Answer (score -1):

here's a good example how to serialize/deserialize an object. http://sharpertutorials.com/serialization/

Comment: @Grasshopper is asking about class generation, not serialization.  This doesn't address the question.

Comment: I think you might be wrong there -- "create the class which can be serialized to XML". The actual requirement is a little vague.

Comment: My fault, I posted the answer at 3 AM, before going to bed :)

Comment: @Tim - I'm going to be pedantic :) "Create the class" is different to "Create the object".

Comment: @Greg -- heh, fair enough :) Although I'd argue that if you're going to be pedantic, maybe we should start talking about generation, definition and instantiation instead of creation as well. Maybe there's a good question in there, or in the community wiki.